# How do you move to another scene in actionscript 3 using buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, event-handling, flash-cs6

I'm trying to use a button to skip from one scene to the first frame from the next scene in Flash CS6, however I keep getting the

> error 2108: the scene was not found.

```
stop();

btnNext.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextScene);

function fl_ClickToGoToNextScene(event:MouseEvent):void {

     gotoAndPlay(1, 'scene2');
}
```

This is my code and ''scene2'' is spelled right, how can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the API for [`gotoAndPlay()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndPlay()), it is an overloaded argument which accepts either a `String` for the label, or an `int` for the frame.  Furthermore, if a second argument is provided, it points to the frame number in the target scene.  A `Scene` should not be confused with a frame `Label`.  Scenes are like multiple MovieClip timelines, each with their own first frames.  According to Adobe,

> [Using scenes is not the best approach because of a number of drawbacks...](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d9d.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8ea63-7ff4)

If you are using the automatically generated names, then it should be *`Scene 2`*, and not *`scene2`*.  Furthermore, although your command will work, it will appear to have done nothing unless you also add `stop()` to the first frame of your new scene.

Alternatively, you could just switch to the [`gotoAndStop()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndStop()) which won't cause your playhead to jump back to the first scene.

```
gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 2");
```